# Validate parameters passed into Constructors during compile time

Tags: java, validation, compilation, annotations

In a huge project with tens of thousands of Java files there are a couple of Java classes where developers may pass in strings as parameters to a constructor class I had implemented

```
public byte[] getProductReport(List<String> products, Date from, Date to) {
    // ... do some stuff before...

    List<ReportParameterDto> reportParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    reportParameters.add(new ReportParameterDto("From (YYYY.MM.DD)", ParameterType.DATE, from));
    reportParameters.add(new ReportParameterDto("To_(YYYY.MM.DD)", ParameterType.DATE, to));
    reportParameters.add(new ReportParameterDto("Products", ParameterType.SELECT, someList));

    return ReportFromCRServerHelper.downloadReport("ProductReporot", reportParameters, ReportFormat.PDF);
}
```

If a developer uses wrong string values downloading a requested report (from a remote Report server) will fail during runtime.

In this example I would like to have some validation checking - during compilation - in order to avoid these errors before they are found by the customer.

I have API methods to obtain parameter values from a report which I hope to use
during compilation of the above method.

In my example the compilation should fail and throw an error highlighting how parameters should look instead:

```
 "From (JJJJ-MM)" is invalid --> should be "From_(JJJJ-MM)"
 "Products" is invalid --> should be "PRODUCT_LIST"
```

Can I detect these parameters (used in above ReportParameterDto constructors) through JAVAX annotation processing?

The few tutorials / blogs that I found dealt with validating parameters in method signatures, not the values passed into methods.

Or are there a more elegant tools available?

Comment: I'd say use enums instead of strings.

Comment: What you're asking for can't be done.  Expressions such as arguments passed to methods get evaluated at run time, not compile time; so it's not possible for the compiler to check their values.

Comment: What you really need is do is to implement the checks as runtime checks, and then change your organization's Software Development Processes so that it is mandatory for developers to develop testcases for the report apps that they deliver to customers.  Consider incorporating a coverage tool into your CI builds.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Your advice is not too bad. Maybe I should just provide fix enumerations for the first argument of ReportParameterDto and make sure that my reporting module knows which parameter fits to which report.
And yes, StephenC good tip, too. Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compile-time tool like the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) can validate the arguments to a method or constructor.  You annotate the parameter types to indicate the permitted values, and then when `javac` runs it issues a warning if an argument may not be compatible with the parameter.

If there is a limited number of possible values, then you can use the [Fake Enum Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#fenum-checker) to treat strings or integers as enumerated values.  (Using a Java `enum` is also a good idea, but may not be possible or convenient because of other code that expects a string or integer.)

If the number of possible values is unlimited, then you can use the [Constant Value Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#constant-value-checker) -- for example, to supply a regular expression that any constant string argument must satisfy.

You can also [define your own compile-time validation](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker) if you want different functionality than is available in the checkers that are distributed with the Checker Framework.

Comment: Although this tool provides the means to check arguments, I've bred long enough and came to the conclusion that it makes more sense to disallow passing in strings for those report parameters and only allow enums instead. In my report module I'll make sure that the actual arguments behind each enum will fit to each report. Nonetheless, your answer is technically the fitting answer to my question. :)